# Viewing IE in Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser

Our intranet seems to be much more IE compatible than Firefox.

I used to use IE Tab some time ago, but had issues so I had to remove it.

Is there a way that I can have an "Internet Explorer" style view in Firefox 3.6.15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a version of the extension called "IE Tab 2" that we use around here with good results. I'm running it on FF 3.6.14 right now with no major issues. It makes SQL Server Reporting Services much more tolerable, that's for sure.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/